# npm -v showing wrong version

Tags: node.js, npm, cmder

I use bash shell from Cmder (A terminal based on ConEmu) on a Windows machine.

I'm following the how-to-npm workshop from nodeschool.io (a site that has a bunch of tutorials which you complete using your command-line). The first module of the npm workshop has you check the version of npm that you have with `npm -v`, and then if that isn't the most recent version, it has you use `npm install -g npm` to get the latest version.

So, I input that command, i.e., `npm install -g npm`, and when I go to verify through how-to-npm (verifying is nodeschool's way of checking to see if you've successfully met the requirements of the challenge), the how-to-npm says that my current version is 7.15.1 (which is indeed the latest version of npm) and so I pass. (Before running `npm install -g npm`, I failed because my npm version was not the latest npm version).

However, when I type `npm -v` again, it still shows 6.14.13 (the old version). I've tried closing and reopening my terminal, reinstalling the latest version again, etc., but `npm -v` keeps showing the old version. This isn't the biggest deal in the world, but I'm wondering why it might be happening. The how-to-npm nodeschool module recognizes that my version is up-to-date but Bash keeps showing the old version number. Even though I ran the install command using Bash, cmd.exe and other shells show the new updated version correctly when inputting `npm -v`. It's only Bash that keeps showing the old version number.

Why is this happening? Why can't I update the npm version that Bash uses.
I've tried `npm install -g npm@latest`, `npm install -g npm@7.15.1` manually, and none of them work. Bash's npm version is stuck on 6.14.13. I can change versions to newer and older ones freely and easily in other shells, but not in Bash.

Edit: I've figured out that doing `bash -c cmd` and then typing `bash` again will show the correct npm version for the duration of that session, but if I exit the terminal and open it again, the npm version is back to the old one.

Edit2: A fix for this is to run powershell as admin and do

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope CurrentUser -Force
npm install -g npm-windows-upgrade
npm-windows-upgrade
```

Comment: It sounds like you might have multiple versions installed. If you are in bash on Cmdr you should be able to use the which command. `which npm` to verify you are using the version you should be.

Comment: @Deadron doing that gives me the path /c/Program Files/nodejs/npm

Comment: That sounds like the standard install path but only you know how your local system is setup.

Comment: @Deadron Wait, how does knowing where it's installed help me verify that I'm using the version I should be?

Comment: You don't install or update `npm` on its own, Each version of node comes with the appropriate `npm` version already bundled. So the only thing you should need to do is make sure your _node_ version is the right one.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I don't understand then... my different terminals show that I'm using different versions of npm despite using the same version of node

Comment: If you are running a cygwin terminal maybe npm is installing into a non shared folder. Try checking npm list -g between the two consoles and verify npm is installed in the same location.

Comment: close all your terminals, then open a new one. That is your baseline. Because updating things that rely on your bash profile or the like means you're going to have to close all your other, now out of date, terminal sessions. (Or, reload your terminal session using `source ~/.bash_profile` or the like. And if you don't know what that means: just close all your old terminals and open a single, new terminal, verify that you have the correct version of node, update it if necessary, and only _then_ start opening multiple terminals).

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I tried that, it didn't work. Cmder still displays a different version than my other terminals :/

Comment: @Deadron Running npm list -g shows the same AppData\Roaming path for both terminals. However, when I do "which npm", I get a different path. And when I do "where npm" in cmd.exe, I get 4 paths

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans To be honest, I think the post in its current state pretty much sums it up. I tried to update the npm version that's installed on my machine as requested by an npm workshop I'm following. I know I successfully upgraded from v6.14.13 to 7.15.1 because the workshop says the upgrade was successful. However, when I check my version with npm -v, it still shows the old version number. This only happens in Cmder. On all other terminals that I've tested, npm -v shows the correct NEW version number. What I'm wondering is WHY Cmder shows the wrong OLD version number.

Comment: Right, and my comment as professional Node dev is: this is super weird, _never_ upgrade npm. Only ever install the correct version of Node, because that _comes with npm_, specifically: the version of npm that is known to work with that version of node. If you use pure Windows, installing the right version of Node is enough, you are done. If you also use WSL, then update your version of node _in WSL_ (e.g. the linux bash that windows lets you use) because it's literally an independent OS running inside of Windows, with its own app installation list and run environment.

Comment: If Cmder uses the windows `cmd` system, it should show the same version as regular `cmd`. If it uses the WSL bash, it'll show the same as `cmd` _only if_ you didn't install node or npm in WSL bash. If you did: congrats, that version will now always win, because WSL bash will _always_ use its own installed applications and only try to run the Windows application if it's not found in the linux subsystem. So it sounds like you made the mistake of installing `npm` (possibly even _without_ Node) in WSL bash. So: open bash, and uninstall npm/node there using `apt`. Let it use Windows' versions.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I understand your prescriptive comment to never do such a thing. It's just an exercise in a "learning npm" type of workshop. However, that doesn't answer my question. I'm not concerned with whether or not I should ever independently install a newer version of npm. I'm wondering why the terminal Cmder and other terminals handle upgrading to a newer version differently. Why do they show different version numbers after running the same npm install -g npm command?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I installed node via the website on my fresh Windows machine. I didn't independently install npm in Bash before I had node. If what you're saying is correct, up until ~an hour ago when I tried to update the npm version from WSL bash, I was using the version of npm that came with my node install which I did NOT do using WSL bash. Aren't you saying then that the WSL bash npm version will win out? It's the opposite though... the version I installed using WSL bash is what shows on cmd.exe, and NOT what is shown in Bash.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I'm not wondering why the Bash version isn't the same as the cmd version per se. Your comment explains that well. I'm wondering why I can't update the Bash version.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I've made the changes you've suggested